# Optimization of Cattle Feed Composition using Python with multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, scipy

I have a DataFrame `df1` representing `different ingredients` `(Maize, Jowar, Bajara Rice_Broken Wheat)` for **cattle feed**, each with associated **cost** and `nutritional parameters` `(ME_Kcal_per_Kg,  C_Protein,  C_Fat and   Chloride)` & **Weight** represents the weight assigned in case to maintain the ratio of different ingredients.

```
               Item  Cost  Weight  ME_(Kcal/Kg)  CProtein_(%)  C_Fat_(%) CFibre_(%)  _Lysine  _Methionine  _Methionine-Cystein    Ca  AvailPhosphorus  Sodium  Chloride  Ingredients_constraints_Min  Ingredients_constraints_Max
              Maize    22       1         3.300           9.0       4.00          2     0.27        0.170                 0.37  0.01             0.08    0.01      0.04                       0.0000                       0.6000
              Jowar    42       1         3.000          10.0       3.00          4     0.22        0.170                 0.38  0.04             0.13    0.01      0.10                       0.0000                       0.3000
             Bajara    20       1         2.640          12.7       4.90        2.2     0.42        0.240                 0.38  0.13             0.36    0.04      0.00                       0.0000                       0.3000
      Rice_(broken)     9       1         2.600           7.9       1.70        1.4     0.26        0.200                 0.37  0.11             0.24    0.04      0.00                       0.0000                       0.1000
              Wheat    24       1         3.100          14.0       2.60        2.5     0.38        0.210                 0.50  0.05             0.14    0.02      0.05                       0.0000                       0.2000
       Barley_Grain    20       1         2.640          11.5       1.90          5     0.44        0.180                 0.42  0.08             0.21    0.03      0.18                       0.0000                       0.1000
        Rice_Polish    22       1         2.700          12.7      14.00          5     0.54        0.240                 0.50  0.27             0.14    0.06      0.07                       0.0000                       0.3000
               Ragi    43       1         2.950          12.6       1.85        2.8     0.36        0.150                 0.36  0.08             0.00    0.00      0.00                       0.0000                       0.3500
      Tapioca_Flour    35       1         3.300           2.0       0.70       12.9     0.06        0.006                 0.01  0.58             0.00    0.00      0.00                       0.0000                       0.1500
      Vegetable_Fat    75       1         8.800           0.0      99.40          0     0.00        0.000                 0.00  0.00             0.00    0.00      0.00                       0.0000                       0.0500
           Soy_Meal    45       1         2.250          44.0       0.80        6.5     2.75        0.640                 1.31  0.40             0.14    0.02      0.05                       0.0000                       0.4000
     Groundnut_Meal    25       1         2.400          44.0       1.00         10     1.39        0.420                 1.10  0.10             0.20    0.07      0.00                       0.0000                       0.3000
   Rapeseed_Extract    28       1         1.900          36.0       1.70       11.5     2.02        0.730                 1.64  0.60             0.25    0.03      0.10                       0.0000                       0.0300
  Sunflower_Extract    25       1         1.540          28.0       1.00         24     1.06        0.670                 1.15  0.35             0.30    0.01      0.05                       0.0000                       0.1000
     Sesame_Extract    25       1         2.200          44.0       0.50        6.1     1.01        1.160                 1.97  2.00             0.24    0.04      0.00                       0.0000                       0.1000
        Fullfat_Soy    50       1         3.300          38.0      18.00          5     2.37        0.510                 1.16  0.25             0.20    0.04      0.08                       0.0000                       0.2500
           Fishmeal    25       1         2.180          45.0       7.00          I     2.50        0.840                 1.15  7.16             1.67    0.19      0.60                       0.0000                       0.1000
    Meat_&_Bonemeal    30       1         1.848          45.0       8.60        2.1     2.48        0.650                 1.16 10.00             5.10    0.60      0.00                       0.0000                       0.0500
       Ricebran_Doc    14       1         1.800          16.0       0.50         14     0.66        0.310                 0.64  0.37             0.00    0.06      0.07                       0.0000                       0.2000
         Wheat_Bran    17       1         1.400          14.5       3.00         11     0.63        0.230                 0.56  0.08             0.40    0.02      0.06                       0.0000                       0.0600
           Molasses    14       1         2.000           3.0       0.00          0     0.00        0.000                 0.00  0.80             0.04    0.16      2.30                       0.0000                       0.0200
   Limestone_Ponder    24       1         0.000           0.0       0.00          0     0.00        0.000                 0.00 38.00             0.00    0.50      0.03                       0.0000                       1.0000
Dicalcium_Phosphate    28       1         0.000           0.0       0.00          0     0.00        0.000                 0.00 23.00            18.00    0.06      0.01                       0.0000                       1.0000
          Bone_Meal    25       1         0.000           0.0       0.00          0     0.00        0.000                 0.00 29.80            12.50    0.04      0.00                       0.0000                       0.0500
         Shell_grit    10       1         0.000           0.0       0.00          0     0.00        0.000                 0.00 38.00             0.10    0.20      0.01                       0.0000                       1.0000
    Sodium_chloride    18       1         0.000           0.0       0.00          0     0.00        0.000                 0.00  0.00             0.00   39.00     60.00                       0.0000                       1.0000
         Sod_Bicarb    32       1         0.000           0.0       0.00          0     0.00        0.000                 0.00  0.00             0.00   27.00      0.00                       0.0000                       1.0000
                Lys    98       1         0.000          94.0       0.00          0    75.00        0.000                 0.00  0.00             0.00    0.00      0.00                       0.0000                       1.0000
      DL_Methionine   102       1         0.000          58.0       0.00          0     0.00       98.000                98.00  0.00             0.00    0.00      0.00                       0.0000                       1.0000
            Min_mix   100       1         0.000           0.0       0.00          0     0.00        0.000                 0.00  0.00             0.00    0.00      0.00                       0.0025                       0.0025
            Vit_Mix   250       1         0.000           0.0       0.00          0     0.00        0.000                 0.00  0.00             0.00    0.00      0.00                       0.0025                       0.0025
```

Another DataFrame `df2` defines **nutrient limits** for the cattle feed.

```
Nutrients_Limits  ME_(Kcal/Kg)  CProtein_(%)  C_Fat_(%)  CFibre_(%)  _Lysine  _Methionine  _Methionine-Cystein  Ca  AvailPhosphorus  Sodium  Chloride
             Min          2.78          26.5          5           5      1.3         0.48                 0.75 0.8              0.3     0.3       0.3
             Max          2.90          28.0          7           7      1.3         0.48                 0.75 0.8              0.3     0.3       0.3
```

***The goal is to find the combination of ingredients from df1 that minimizes cost while meeting the nutritional constraints defined in df2.***

**The conditions are:**

*1. The quantity of each ingredient should not exceed the values specified in the Ingredients_constraints_Max column in df1.*

*2. The quantity of each ingredient should not fall below the values specified in the Ingredients_constraints_Min column in df1.*

*3. The combination of different ingredients should not exceed 100 in total.*

*4. The nutritional parameters (Weight, ME_Kcal_per_Kg, C_Protein, C_Fat, Chloride) should meet the limits specified in df2.*

The Code Snipped for 1st condition is here, unable to integrate second condition.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import linprog

# Extracting relevant data from the DataFrame
costs = df1['Cost'].values
constraints_min = df1['Ingredients_constraints_Min'].values
constraints_max = df1['Ingredients_constraints_Max'].values

# Coefficients for the linear programming problem
c = costs
A_eq = np.ones((1, len(costs)))
b_eq = np.array([100])

# Bounds for each ingredient quantity
bounds = [(constraints_min[i], constraints_max[i]) for i in range(len(costs))]

# Solving the linear programming problem
result = linprog(c, A_eq=A_eq, b_eq=b_eq, bounds=bounds, method='highs')

# Extracting the solution
solution_quantities = result.x

# Displaying the results
for i, item in enumerate(df1['Item']):
    print(f"{item}: {solution_quantities[i]}")

print(f"Total Cost: {result.fun}")
```

How can I find the combination of ingredients that minimizes cost while satisfying these nutritional constraints?

Comment: Is your question on how to include `df2` in your optimization?

Comment: Yes, the nutritional parameters (Weight, ME_Kcal_per_Kg, C_Protein, C_Fat, Chloride) of the resulting final feed for cattle consumption should have to be in the lower and upper limits specified in df2

Comment: Why is your equality constraint set to be 100? Shouldn't that be an inequality?

Comment: Here ```b_eq = np.array([100])```?, taken 100 coz Ingredients constraints should not be more than 100%.

Comment: But you're saying you want 100 ingredients, not that you want at most 100 ingredients.

Comment: I do not want 100 ingredients, its like if i am preparing a feed from maize, bajra and jowar, then i can only take jowar upto 30%, not more than that in the feed mixture of 100%.

Comment: Is this problem feasible? You have a minimum amount of Maize = 10, which corresponds to 33.0 ME_Kcal_per_Kg. That already exceeds the maximum.

Comment: And I know you don't 100, but that's what you told the solver. You told it that you require the total number of ingredients to be 100. You should have used `A_ub` and `b_ub` for that.

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/abhilashsinghimd/AASD_Geojson/main/Broiler%20chick.xlsx

Comment: This excel file has a solver function, you can get a rough idea from it. For here i have just used a few columns.

Comment: Can you address my specific question about Maize?

Comment: minimum amount for everything is zero, it’s a typing error. For Maize it will also be = 0

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark Setting the minima to 0 fixes the initial Maize issue. Whether the problem is feasible still remains to be seen.

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark They seem to have taken a subset of the problem for this question. While the whole problem may be feasible, this subset may not be.

Comment: Can you explain how **Weight** should be considered? Maybe **Weight x ME_Kcal_per_Kg**?. The problem looks like infeasible due to Max constraints.

Comment: @Corralien, for now, it was taken 1 only. The purpose was to make the cattle feed/diet based on ratios like Maize, Bajara, and Rice_Broken feed in the ratio 2:1:1 then weights assigned would be 0.5, 0.25, 0.25

Comment: @jared, I have updated the whole Dataset.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is feasible?

Comment: I totally agree with @jared. You can check our answers.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a subset of the actual problem, the subset may not be feasible. That said, I believe the code I am about to sure will work, though I cannot test it.

For the nutrients, you want to create `A_ub` and `b_ub` to define the upper and lower bounds of the nutrient values. The upper bounds are simple, you just set the nutrient values in `A_ub` and the max in `b_ub`. For the lower bounds, since we have a less than or equal constraint, we have to negative all the terms so it applies a greater than or equal to constraint.

You also word the ingredient limit as no exceeding 100, which made me think it needs to be less than or equal to 100, but I think I now understand that to mean it should equal 100.

```py
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import linprog

df1 = pd.read_csv("df1.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("df2.csv")

costs = df1["Cost"].values
ingredients_min = df1["Ingredients_constraints_Min"].values
ingredients_max = df1["Ingredients_constraints_Max"].values

A_ub = []
b_ub = []
for nutrient in df2.columns[1:]:
    A_ub.append(df1[nutrient].to_list())
    A_ub.append([-n for n in df1[nutrient].to_list()])
    nutrient_min, nutrient_max = df2[nutrient].to_list()
    b_ub.append([nutrient_max])
    b_ub.append([-nutrient_min])

A_eq = [[1]*len(costs)]
b_eq = [100]

bounds = list(zip(ingredients_min, ingredients_max))

result = linprog(costs, A_eq=A_eq, b_eq=b_eq, A_ub=A_ub, b_ub=b_ub, bounds=None)

if result.success:
    solution_quantities = result.x
    for i, item in enumerate(df1["Item"]):
        print(f"{item}: {solution_quantities[i]}")
    
    print(f"Total Cost: {result.fun}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems not to be feasible because the gap between the upper and lower bound (`df2`) is not large enough.

In addition to Jared's answer, you can visualize the A, b and c matrix with `Pandas`:

```
nutrients = ['energy', 'protein', 'fat', 'fibre', 'lysine', 'methionine', 'cystein', 'calcium', 'phosphorus', 'sodium', 'chloride']

A_item_100 = pd.DataFrame(1, columns=df1.index, index=['items_sum'])
A_nutr_min = -df1.loc[:, 'ME_(Kcal/Kg)':'Chloride'].set_axis(nutrients, axis=1).add_suffix('_min').T
A_nutr_max = df1.loc[:, 'ME_(Kcal/Kg)':'Chloride'].set_axis(nutrients, axis=1).add_suffix('_max').T

b_item_100 = pd.Series(100, index=['items_sum'])
b_nutr_min = -df2.T['Min'].set_axis(nutrients).add_suffix('_min')
b_nutr_max = df2.T['Max'].set_axis(nutrients).add_suffix('_max')

A_ub = pd.concat([A_item_100, A_nutr_min, A_nutr_max])
b_ub = pd.concat([b_item_100, b_nutr_min, b_nutr_max])
c = pd.DataFrame(1, columns=df1.index, index=['c'])

bounds = df1[['Ingredients_constraints_Min', 'Ingredients_constraints_Max']]
model = pd.concat([pd.concat([A_ub, b_ub.to_frame('b')], axis=1), c], axis=0)
```

Output (`b` is the last column and `c` is the last row):

```
>>> model
                        Jowar   Bajara   Rice_(broken)   Wheat   Barley_Grain   Rice_Polish   Ragi   Tapioca_Flour   Vegetable_Fat   Soy_Meal   Groundnut_Meal   Rapeseed_Extract   Sunflower_Extract   Sesame_Extract   Fullfat_Soy   Fishmeal   Meat_&_Bonemeal   Ricebran_Doc   Wheat_Bran   Molasses   Limestone_Ponder   Dicalcium_Phosphate   Bone_Meal   Shell_grit   Sodium_chloride   Sod_Bicarb   Lys   DL_Methionine   Min_mix   Vit_Mix        b
                Maize                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
# Sum(nutrients) <= 100
items_sum        1.00     1.00     1.00            1.00    1.00           1.00          1.00   1.00           1.000             1.0       1.00             1.00               1.00                1.00             1.00          1.00       1.00             1.000           1.00         1.00       1.00               1.00                  1.00        1.00         1.00               1.0          1.0   1.0             1.0       1.0       1.0  100.00

# Min constraints
energy_min      -3.30    -3.00    -2.64           -2.60   -3.10          -2.64         -2.70  -2.95          -3.300            -8.8      -2.25            -2.40              -1.90               -1.54            -2.20         -3.30      -2.18            -1.848          -1.80        -1.40      -2.00              -0.00                 -0.00       -0.00        -0.00              -0.0         -0.0  -0.0            -0.0      -0.0      -0.0   -2.78
protein_min     -9.00   -10.00   -12.70           -7.90  -14.00         -11.50        -12.70 -12.60          -2.000            -0.0     -44.00           -44.00             -36.00              -28.00           -44.00        -38.00     -45.00           -45.000         -16.00       -14.50      -3.00              -0.00                 -0.00       -0.00        -0.00              -0.0         -0.0 -94.0           -58.0      -0.0      -0.0  -26.50
fat_min         -4.00    -3.00    -4.90           -1.70   -2.60          -1.90        -14.00  -1.85          -0.700           -99.4      -0.80            -1.00              -1.70               -1.00            -0.50        -18.00      -7.00            -8.600          -0.50        -3.00      -0.00              -0.00                 -0.00       -0.00        -0.00              -0.0         -0.0  -0.0            -0.0      -0.0      -0.0   -5.00
fibre_min       -2.00    -4.00    -2.20           -1.40   -2.50          -5.00         -5.00  -2.80         -12.900            -0.0      -6.50           -10.00             -11.50              -24.00            -6.10         -5.00      -1.00            -2.100         -14.00       -11.00      -0.00              -0.00                 -0.00       -0.00        -0.00              -0.0         -0.0  -0.0            -0.0      -0.0      -0.0   -5.00
lysine_min      -0.27    -0.22    -0.42           -0.26   -0.38          -0.44         -0.54  -0.36          -0.060            -0.0      -2.75            -1.39              -2.02               -1.06            -1.01         -2.37      -2.50            -2.480          -0.66        -0.63      -0.00              -0.00                 -0.00       -0.00        -0.00              -0.0         -0.0 -75.0            -0.0      -0.0      -0.0   -1.30
methionine_min  -0.17    -0.17    -0.24           -0.20   -0.21          -0.18         -0.24  -0.15          -0.006            -0.0      -0.64            -0.42              -0.73               -0.67            -1.16         -0.51      -0.84            -0.650          -0.31        -0.23      -0.00              -0.00                 -0.00       -0.00        -0.00              -0.0         -0.0  -0.0           -98.0      -0.0      -0.0   -0.48
cystein_min     -0.37    -0.38    -0.38           -0.37   -0.50          -0.42         -0.50  -0.36          -0.010            -0.0      -1.31            -1.10              -1.64               -1.15            -1.97         -1.16      -1.15            -1.160          -0.64        -0.56      -0.00              -0.00                 -0.00       -0.00        -0.00              -0.0         -0.0  -0.0           -98.0      -0.0      -0.0   -0.75
calcium_min     -0.01    -0.04    -0.13           -0.11   -0.05          -0.08         -0.27  -0.08          -0.580            -0.0      -0.40            -0.10              -0.60               -0.35            -2.00         -0.25      -7.16           -10.000          -0.37        -0.08      -0.80             -38.00                -23.00      -29.80       -38.00              -0.0         -0.0  -0.0            -0.0      -0.0      -0.0   -0.80
phosphorus_min  -0.08    -0.13    -0.36           -0.24   -0.14          -0.21         -0.14  -0.00          -0.000            -0.0      -0.14            -0.20              -0.25               -0.30            -0.24         -0.20      -1.67            -5.100          -0.00        -0.40      -0.04              -0.00                -18.00      -12.50        -0.10              -0.0         -0.0  -0.0            -0.0      -0.0      -0.0   -0.30
sodium_min      -0.01    -0.01    -0.04           -0.04   -0.02          -0.03         -0.06  -0.00          -0.000            -0.0      -0.02            -0.07              -0.03               -0.01            -0.04         -0.04      -0.19            -0.600          -0.06        -0.02      -0.16              -0.50                 -0.06       -0.04        -0.20             -39.0        -27.0  -0.0            -0.0      -0.0      -0.0   -0.30
chloride_min    -0.04    -0.10    -0.00           -0.00   -0.05          -0.18         -0.07  -0.00          -0.000            -0.0      -0.05            -0.00              -0.10               -0.05            -0.00         -0.08      -0.60            -0.000          -0.07        -0.06      -2.30              -0.03                 -0.01       -0.00        -0.01             -60.0         -0.0  -0.0            -0.0      -0.0      -0.0   -0.30

# Max constraints
energy_max       3.30     3.00     2.64            2.60    3.10           2.64          2.70   2.95           3.300             8.8       2.25             2.40               1.90                1.54             2.20          3.30       2.18             1.848           1.80         1.40       2.00               0.00                  0.00        0.00         0.00               0.0          0.0   0.0             0.0       0.0       0.0    2.90
protein_max      9.00    10.00    12.70            7.90   14.00          11.50         12.70  12.60           2.000             0.0      44.00            44.00              36.00               28.00            44.00         38.00      45.00            45.000          16.00        14.50       3.00               0.00                  0.00        0.00         0.00               0.0          0.0  94.0            58.0       0.0       0.0   28.00
fat_max          4.00     3.00     4.90            1.70    2.60           1.90         14.00   1.85           0.700            99.4       0.80             1.00               1.70                1.00             0.50         18.00       7.00             8.600           0.50         3.00       0.00               0.00                  0.00        0.00         0.00               0.0          0.0   0.0             0.0       0.0       0.0    7.00
fibre_max        2.00     4.00     2.20            1.40    2.50           5.00          5.00   2.80          12.900             0.0       6.50            10.00              11.50               24.00             6.10          5.00       1.00             2.100          14.00        11.00       0.00               0.00                  0.00        0.00         0.00               0.0          0.0   0.0             0.0       0.0       0.0    7.00
lysine_max       0.27     0.22     0.42            0.26    0.38           0.44          0.54   0.36           0.060             0.0       2.75             1.39               2.02                1.06             1.01          2.37       2.50             2.480           0.66         0.63       0.00               0.00                  0.00        0.00         0.00               0.0          0.0  75.0             0.0       0.0       0.0    1.30
methionine_max   0.17     0.17     0.24            0.20    0.21           0.18          0.24   0.15           0.006             0.0       0.64             0.42               0.73                0.67             1.16          0.51       0.84             0.650           0.31         0.23       0.00               0.00                  0.00        0.00         0.00               0.0          0.0   0.0            98.0       0.0       0.0    0.48
cystein_max      0.37     0.38     0.38            0.37    0.50           0.42          0.50   0.36           0.010             0.0       1.31             1.10               1.64                1.15             1.97          1.16       1.15             1.160           0.64         0.56       0.00               0.00                  0.00        0.00         0.00               0.0          0.0   0.0            98.0       0.0       0.0    0.75
calcium_max      0.01     0.04     0.13            0.11    0.05           0.08          0.27   0.08           0.580             0.0       0.40             0.10               0.60                0.35             2.00          0.25       7.16            10.000           0.37         0.08       0.80              38.00                 23.00       29.80        38.00               0.0          0.0   0.0             0.0       0.0       0.0    0.80
phosphorus_max   0.08     0.13     0.36            0.24    0.14           0.21          0.14   0.00           0.000             0.0       0.14             0.20               0.25                0.30             0.24          0.20       1.67             5.100           0.00         0.40       0.04               0.00                 18.00       12.50         0.10               0.0          0.0   0.0             0.0       0.0       0.0    0.30
sodium_max       0.01     0.01     0.04            0.04    0.02           0.03          0.06   0.00           0.000             0.0       0.02             0.07               0.03                0.01             0.04          0.04       0.19             0.600           0.06         0.02       0.16               0.50                  0.06        0.04         0.20              39.0         27.0   0.0             0.0       0.0       0.0    0.30
chloride_max     0.04     0.10     0.00            0.00    0.05           0.18          0.07   0.00           0.000             0.0       0.05             0.00               0.10                0.05             0.00          0.08       0.60             0.000           0.07         0.06       2.30               0.03                  0.01        0.00         0.01              60.0          0.0   0.0             0.0       0.0       0.0    0.30

# Objective
c                1.00     1.00     1.00            1.00    1.00           1.00          1.00   1.00           1.000             1.0       1.00             1.00               1.00                1.00             1.00          1.00       1.00             1.000           1.00         1.00       1.00               1.00                  1.00        1.00         1.00               1.0          1.0   1.0             1.0       1.0       1.0     NaN
```

The optimization is not feasible:

```
res = linprog(c, A_ub, b_ub, bounds=bounds)
print(res)

# Output
       message: The problem is infeasible. (HiGHS Status 8: model_status is Infeasible; primal_status is At lower/fixed bound)
       success: False
        status: 2
           fun: None
             x: None
           nit: 16
         lower:  residual: None
                marginals: None
         upper:  residual: None
                marginals: None
         eqlin:  residual: None
                marginals: None
       ineqlin:  residual: None
                marginals: None
```

However if you relax the `b_nutr_max` bound (multiply it by 2 for example), your problem is feasible:

```
b_ub = pd.concat([b_item_100, b_nutr_min, b_nutr_max*2])

res = linprog(c, A_ub, b_ub, bounds=bounds)
print(res)

# Output
        message: Optimization terminated successfully. (HiGHS Status 7: Optimal)
        success: True
         status: 0
            fun: 0.8744209405007407
              x: [ 1.539e-01  0.000e+00 ...  2.500e-03  2.500e-03]
            nit: 10
          lower:  residual: [ 1.539e-01  0.000e+00 ...  0.000e+00
                              0.000e+00]
                 marginals: [ 0.000e+00  7.033e-02 ...  1.000e+00
                              1.000e+00]
          upper:  residual: [ 4.461e-01  3.000e-01 ...  0.000e+00
                              0.000e+00]
                 marginals: [ 0.000e+00  0.000e+00 ...  0.000e+00
                              0.000e+00]
          eqlin:  residual: []
                 marginals: []
        ineqlin:  residual: [ 9.913e+01  0.000e+00 ...  3.000e-01
                              1.428e-01]
                 marginals: [-0.000e+00 -2.829e-01 ... -0.000e+00
                             -0.000e+00]
 mip_node_count: 0
 mip_dual_bound: 0.0
        mip_gap: 0.0
```

Variables:

```
>>> pd.Series(res.x, index=df1.index)
Item
Maize                  0.153908
Jowar                  0.000000
Bajara                 0.000000
Rice_(broken)          0.000000
Wheat                  0.000000
Barley_Grain           0.000000
Rice_Polish            0.000000
Ragi                   0.000000
Tapioca_Flour          0.060763
Vegetable_Fat          0.050000
Soy_Meal               0.000000
Groundnut_Meal         0.255666
Rapeseed_Extract       0.000000
Sunflower_Extract      0.000000
Sesame_Extract         0.000000
Fullfat_Soy            0.250000
Fishmeal               0.079619
Meat_&_Bonemeal        0.010508
Ricebran_Doc           0.000000
Wheat_Bran             0.000000
Molasses               0.000000
Limestone_Ponder       0.000000
Dicalcium_Phosphate    0.000000
Bone_Meal              0.000000
Shell_grit             0.000000
Sodium_chloride        0.006388
Sod_Bicarb             0.000000
Lys                    0.001091
DL_Methionine          0.001478
Min_mix                0.002500
Vit_Mix                0.002500
```

However, I don't think it's the result you want but it's a good starting point to build `A_ub`, `b_ub` and `c` arrays.